# How to read the returned complex object values when calling a method by reflection using 'Invoke' in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, invoke, system.reflection

[image: Intellisense]

As you can see in the picture I see the return values from the call but I cannot use them.
How can I convert the return object to something else. This function is dynamic so I cannot use a reference object for this class.

Comment: Set `Option Strict Off` and just call `oRes(0).CustomerName` or whatever.

Comment: Thank you for your response...

Comment: The problem is that the returned object can be different depending on what method I call, I do not know what the member names are. I need to somehow read those values into an array or collection so I can access them by index. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What can you assume about the returned object? For example can you assume that it is an array? Can you assume that elements in the array have specific properties? How are you going to use the data from the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you! 
I managed to read the object by using this

`Dim oResults As Object = oMethod.Invoke(oUbCustomerService, oParameterValues)
For Each oResult in oResults
   Dim oFieldInfoList() As FieldInfo = oResult.GetType().GetFields
   dim strValue as String = oFieldInfoList(n).GetValue(oResult)
...
Next`